# Apple Script to run an application as root

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, root, sudo

I am trying to use an Apple Script to run an application as root without asking for password all the time. I used this Apple Script code:

```
do shell script "/Applications/MyApp.app" user name "<username>" password "<password>" with administrator privileges
```

This works, but it makes the Apple Script to keep on running without closing. Not only that, the application that runs using this Apple Script gets stuck and could not be closed unless macOS is restarted. Even Force Quit is not working.

I also tried this method,

I created another script that can allow the app to run as root without asking for password. Here is that code,

```
set sudoersFilePath to "/etc/sudoers"
set newEntry to "username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /Applications/MyApp.app"

do shell script "echo " & quoted form of newEntry & " | sudo tee -a " & sudoersFilePath with administrator privileges
```

The above script adds a line in the `sudoers` file. You can access this file from Terminal using this command,

```
sudo visudo
```

This will list all the files in the list that do not require password all the time. In the `sudoers` file, it has added the line to give full root access to the macOS user. This file contains the required application, but it is not running as root.

So, how to run the application as root without asking for password using Apple Script or any other method?

---

This script, as I mentioned above, works,

```
do shell script "/Applications/MyApp.app" user name "<username>" password "<password>" with administrator privileges
```

But, it is making Apple Script and the application to continually run. Even Force Quit is not working. Is there a way to fix this from continually run and be able to quit it?

Comment: How is this related to _bash_?

Comment: Possibly, the OP’s default scripting language is bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) and [Vincent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7685439/vincent) for the information provided. I found a solution. This **Apple Script** worked:

```
do shell script "/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp > /dev/null 2>&1 &" user name "username" password "password" with administrator privileges
quit
```

It would seem that some macOS application are restricted way too much that prevents it from running as root without asking for password. But, it worked on other applications.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to retrieve a password from the Keychain. However, you must allow its usage at least once.

```
set myPassword to do shell script "echo $(security find-generic-password -a $USER -s MyApp -w)"

do shell script "echo " & myPassword & " | sudo -S /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

Sources :

https://www.netmeister.org/blog/keychain-passwords.html

> $ security find-generic-password -a ${USER} -s playground -w

https://ss64.com/mac/security-password-mgt.html

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/323661?sortBy=best

> The '> /dev/null' suppresses stdout; '2>&1' suppresses stderr
> (specifically, sends stderr to the same place as stdout), and the
> trailing '&' puts the command in the background.
>
> Using this suffix
> will return control to your AppleScript immediately, leaving the shell
> process running in the background.

https://ss64.com/mac/sudo.html

> -S  The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from
> standard
> input instead of the terminal device.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html

Comment: Thank you. I will check this solution and reply back to you.

Comment: When this script runs, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the original AppleScript, where it keeps running without closing, is likely due to the way it launches the application directly and waits for it to finish. When you launch an application in this manner (especially with administrator privileges), the script may not return control until the application is closed, which can cause the script and the application to appear stuck.

Modifying the `sudoers` file as you did can be risky and should be done with caution.
A safer approach could be to use a shell script wrapper `runMyAppAsRoot.sh` that runs your application with root privileges. That script can be invoked from your AppleScript.

The shell script can be designed to execute the application in the background. That means the script launches the app and then immediately returns, not waiting for the app to close.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
nohup sudo /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyAppExecutable &> /dev/null &
```

With:

- `nohup`: Makes sure the process is not terminated even if the parent shell closes.
- `&>`: Redirects both stdout and stderr to `/dev/null` (effectively silencing output).
  Or you can redirect to a log file if you want to keep a record of the output: `&> /path/to/logfile.log`.
- `&`: Puts the process in the background.

Your AppleScript would then be:

```
do shell script "/path/to/runMyAppAsRoot.sh" with administrator privileges
```

---

The OP's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77847953/6309) is

```bash
do shell script "/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp" user name "username" password "password" with administrator privileges
quit
```

By specifying the path to the application's actual executable (`/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp`), it bypasses any wrapper scripts or additional checks that might be present when launching the app normally (i.e., just using `/Applications/MyApp.app`).

The `with administrator privileges` clause allows the script to run the application with elevated privileges, which is necessary for certain tasks that require root access.

The `quit` command at the end of the script is a good practice to make sure the AppleScript stops executing once it has launched the application. That prevents the script from lingering in a running state.

Comment: Thank you. I will check this and reply back.

Comment: I get this error message: `error "/bin/sh: /Users/myuser/Desktop/my.sh: Operation not permitted" number 126`

Comment: I tried it and still the same error. I added the **Terminal** and **Script Editor** to _Full-Disk Access_ and I executed `chmod +x /Users/myuser/Desktop/my.sh`. But, no change, same result.

Comment: [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc), I have updated the question.

Comment: @CodenameK OK. I have left a suggestion in my edited answer.

Comment: It does not run the application.

Comment: @CodenameK I am sorry for your bounty if you have not found a solution. You could redirect the output to a file `&> /tmp/aFile`, just to confirm whether the application is running or not (by looking if the `/tmp/aFile` is at least created).

Comment: It is OK. You did provide me a lot of information that helped me to identify the issue and find a solution.

Comment: @CodenameK I have referenced your solution in my answer, with some explanations added to it.